# angular 5 filter returns only single columns in a table rather than the entire row

Tags: angular, filter

Here's the link for stackblitz: stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uswjr1. The function is tied to a button that opens a csv file from "assets" folder. Path is in asd-match.component.ts as: '../assets/asd_matches.csv'. StackBlitz won't let me post a csv file, but will post a sample bit of content:

Application_Name,Server_Name,IP_Address,IT_Manager_First,IT_Manager_Last Medforce,medforce1.contoso.com,10.205.44.2,Richard,Davis SAS,sasserver1.contoso.com,10.205.44.3,Michael,Collins Qualys,qualysscan1.contoso.com,10.205.44.4,Alex,Lifeson Outlook,outlook1.contoso.com,10.205.44.5,Getty,Lee

Code for importing file for view in browser seems to work for both text and csv files. Non-comma-separated content can be filtered correctly, because it's only one column. When filtering multiple columns, however, only the individual column(s) with matching content come back, rather than the entire row.

So my question, is whether there's a way to make the filter pull the entire row?

Comment: Your example is horrible to reason about. Put your code on stackblitz and provide example of your JSON structure. By the way, https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Comment: Edit your question instead of writing everything in comments.

Comment: Apologies, just updated StackBlitz, realizing I was missing the input search box. Had reverted my code back while waiting to find an answer. Anyway, code has been updated on StackBlitz. Thank you.